# python argparse.ArgumentParser read config file

Tags: python, python-3.x, copy, argparse, shutil

Im trying to add the switch -c and specify the config file.
I have it working at the moment using the config.dat but when i use -c and specify a new .dat it uses the default config.dat....

Any idea where im going wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import argparse
import shutil

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Copy multiple Files from a specified data file')
parser.add_argument('-c', '--configfile', default="config.dat",help='file to read the config from')


def read_config(data):
    try:
        dest = '/home/admin/Documents/backup/'
        #Read in date from config.dat
        data = open('config.dat')
        #Interate through list of files '\n'
        filelist = data.read().split('\n')
        #Copy through interated list and strip white spaces and empty lines
        for file in filelist:
            if file:
                shutil.copy(file.strip(), dest)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass

args =parser.parse_args()
read = read_config(args.configfile)
args =parser.parse_args()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works by converting the args to a dictionary, then getting the value via key. Also, the code you had on line 13 didn't open the passed in value. This one opens the passed in file. See if this works for you:

```
# !/usr/bin/python3
import argparse
import shutil

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Copy multiple Files from a specified data file')
parser.add_argument('-c', '--configfile', default="config.dat", help='file to read the config from')


def read_config(data):
    try:
        dest = '/home/admin/Documents/backup/'
        # Read in date from config.dat
        data = open(data)
        # Interate through list of files '\n'
        filelist = data.read().split('\n')
        # Copy through interated list and strip white spaces and empty lines
        for file in filelist:
            if file:
                shutil.copy(file.strip(), dest)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass


args = vars(parser.parse_args())
read = read_config(args['configfile'])
```

Comment: That worked perfectly.  Thanks everyone.  Easier to understand :)

Answer (score 3):

Take a close look at what you are doing on line 14. Even though you are retrieving and assigning the `--configfile` argument to `args` you are still using a string literal `data = open('config.dat')` instead of passing `data` (which is the value of your argument for the configfile passed as an argument to the function `read_config`):

```
def read_config(data):
    try:
        dest = '/home/admin/Documents/backup/'
        #Read in date from config.dat
        data = open(data)
        ...
```

I would also change the naming of the argument `data` you are passing to `read_config`-- it's a bit ambiguous. You know that this function expects a file name as an argument so why not simply call it `filename`.

```
def read_config(filename):
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    try:
        dest = '/home/admin/Documents/backup/'
        #Read in date from config.dat
        data = open(filename)
        #Interate through list of files '\n'
        filelist = data.read().split('\n')
        #Copy through interated list and strip white spaces and empty lines
        for file in filelist:
            if file:
                shutil.copy(file.strip(), dest)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass
```

Comment: That makes sense now.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

Make proper use of the function argument; names changed to clarify the nature of the variables.

```
def read_config(filename='config.dat'):
    try:
        dest = '/home/admin/Documents/backup/'
        afile = open(filename)
        #Interate through list of files '\n'
        filelist = afile.read().split('\n')
        #Copy through interated list and strip white spaces and empty lines
        for file in filelist:
            if file:
                shutil.copy(file.strip(), dest)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass
```

Comment: I don't think you'd need to add a default argument value `filename='config.dat'` right? since the default passed should always be `config.dat` from the argument parser `parser.add_argument('-c', '--configfile', default="config.dat",help='file to read the config from')`

Comment: A bit of default redundancy doesn't hurt (usually).  With it the function can be used via an import, with just `read_config()`.